# Why is there an issue with the ADD_MONTHS function in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using the online APEX Oracle DB for some training and have ran into a problem with one of the functions that has me scratching my head.

I have done some testing and have been able to get it to work the long hand way but not the shortened syntax. Using the shortened syntax returns an error which I can't figure out.  Any help would be appreciated.

What I have tried:

`select add_months('2015/10/12', 4) from dual`
returns an error:

> `ORA-01846: not a valid day of the week`

What I got to work:

`select add_months(to_date('2015/10/12', 'yyyy/mm/dd'), 4) from dual`

when I use the `add_months(to_date())` format

I get back the correct result of, `Friday, 12 February, 2016`

If I use the `add_months(arg1, arg2)` it returns the error.

Answer (score 2):

`add_months` expects `date` but you are providing `VARCHAR` without formatting which causes unexpected errors.

Basically oracle cannot implicitly converts given format to date

[image]

Comment: I understand that but if I run sysdate like this select add_months(sysdate, 4) from dual I get this returned like I would expect Sunday, 02 June, 2019

Comment: because sysdate is date, implicit conversion from varchar to date is not the case for sysdate

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this figured out.  I ran `systimestamp` and this was what was returned :

`Saturday, 02 February, 2019`.

I then took and plugged in this into the function I was having trouble with

`select add_months(systimestamp, 4) from dual` and it returned the correct result :

`Sunday, 02 June, 2019` depending on my date formatting.

Comment: `systimestamp` is a `TIMESTAMP`, which can be implicitly cast to `DATE`. `sysdate` is a `DATE` which is what the function expects. `date '2015-10-12'` would be a date (see [literals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Literals.html)). `'2015/10/12'` is just a string which may or not be convertible to a date depending on your session's format defaults.

Answer (score 0):

Find you current `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` with below SQL

```
SELECT value FROM v$nls_parameters WHERE parameter ='NLS_DATE_FORMAT';
```

Basically when you pass a date as varchar2 string, this format is used for the implicit date conversion.

So, instead of dealing with the default date format, we should always use explicit date conversion using `TO_DATE()`

Comment: This is what is being returned from that command, fmDay, fmDD fmMonth, YYYY

Comment: Yeah so, without an explicit format specified in your query, 2015 is interpreted as a Day and hence the error!

Comment: Okay thanks for the answer.  I think I got it figured out